# Changing contents of a Div to cycle through ADs or Content or Whatever

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that I am developing and I have multiple Divs on the main page.  I have a div on the right side of the page labeled right_bar2 and I want it to change every 5-10 seconds.  The entire div will just be an image that is a link.  Basically I assumed the easiest way to do this would be to have a div with a bunch of hidden div's in it and then maybe some javascript that unhides one div at a time and then hides it again and unhides another.  However I am unsure the best way to do it.  I have looked at a bunch of example and can't get it to work 100% correctly.

Thanks for any advice ;)

JsFiddle examples would be great!

I tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/VENLh/4/ but in my rails environment/setup, it breaks multiple things, so I'd like something cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up a bit in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VENLh/6/), but if you said the original breaks multiple things in your original environment, this might not fix them.  What specifically did it break?

What I cleaned up was to avoid the need to keep a manual count of the DIVs for the JS or to worry about their IDs.  The code is pretty simple:

```
$(function() {
    var $divs = $('div', '#container'),
        total = $divs.length,
        counter = 0,

        showDiv = function() {
            $divs.stop().hide();
            $($divs[counter]).show('fast');
            counter = (conter + 1) % total;
            setTimeout(showDiv, 3000);
        };
    $divs.hide();
    showDiv();
});
```

​I didn't perform one optimization that should probably be done.  You probably should cache the results of the jQuery selectors on each DIV.  It would be easy to do with a jQuery `map` statement, but I didn't want to muddy the waters here.

Comment: Performed that optimization in [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VENLh/7/).  This avoids calling the jQuery constructor in each iteration.

Comment: this worked, thanks!... any way to make it to where the user can select the div manually if they don't want to wait for the cycle to scroll through?

Comment: Yes, of course.  But it would take a bit more work.  You would need to store the result of the `setTimeout` call so that you can later clear it.  You would have to expose additional means to call `showDiv` and either create a similar function which scrolls backwards, or pass in a direction parameter to this one or pass in an index parameter to this one to determine which DIV to show.  None of this is particularly difficult, but it's all real work.

Comment: one last thing that is probably simple...any way to get it to choose a random div to start with, instead of the first on the list?

Comment: I would think that replacing `counter = 0;` with `counter = Math.floor(total * Math.random());` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see in this case is if you are going to use heavy image, it may take some time to load. As the image will start getting loaded when you show it first time. So for this I would say you should keep the opacity 0 and load the image at the time of pageload.

And also to remove the delay you are having where one div is getting hidden and other is getting visible can be removed by using opacity. reduce opacity of one from 100 to 0% and for other increase from  0 to 100%.